# Filtering occurs only on the first page

Tags: reactjs

I make a request to the local server using `fetch` and get the response(category list). This response I display on page in view table-list.

With the list, I do these operations:

- Pagination
- Filtering by title name

I can implement this operations using query param: `page` - number current page, `q` - filtering by name category.

When user make some action - changes `value` in some field `in the component state` and I put `value` in query param in URL like this:

```
const response = await fetch(`path?page=${valuePage}&q=${valueFilter}`)
```

1. When I click button **page 1**:

I get from server this response:

```
{"total":7,"perPage":3,"page":1,"lastPage":3,
"data":[
{"id":1,"title":"animals"},
{"id":2,"title":"space"},
{"id":3,"title":"sport"}]}
```

2. When I click button **page 2**:

I get from server this response:

```
{"total":7,"perPage":3,"page":2,"lastPage":3,
"data":[
{"id":4,"title":"paint"},
{"id":5,"title":"it"},
{"id":6,"title":"books"}]}
```

**Etc...**

---

*But I have problem  with filtering:*

### Filtering occurs only on the first page.

---

## How to fix this problem?

I **comment** lines which related with filtering.

## Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    currentPage: 2, 
    buttonsPagination: 0,   
    searchInput: ""                 //set value of my input - empty string
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(currentPage, searchInput ) {     // in this argument I will put values from the state
        const res = await apiCategory('/.....', {
          method: 'GET'
        }, currentPage, searchInput);
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: res.data,                    
            currentPage: res.page,
            buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage),
         }));
    }
    fetchData(value.currentPage, value.searchInput);    // Here I already put the value from the state
  }, [value.currentPage, value.searchInput]);         // also here I wrote value.searchInput

  const changePage = (argPage) => {    
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      currentPage: argPage,
    }));
  };
    
  const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) =>{         // using this method I change field SearchInput
     setValue({
        ...value,                       
        searchInput: event.target.value      // here I put value which user wrote in input
    });
   };


  return (
    <div>
        
     <Search value={value.searchInput} userEnteredValue={upadateStateSearchInput}/>  // my search input (Search component)
     
      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} />
                 
      <div className="button-pagination">
           {[...Array(value.buttonsPagination)].map((item, index) => (
              <button key={'listCategory' + index}   
                      onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}>{index + 1}
              </button>
           ))}
      </div>  
   </div>
  );
};
```

### apiCategory.js:

```
export const apiCategory = async (url, args, valuePage, valueFilter) => { // I will put here value from state
  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${url}?page=${valuePage}&q=${valueFilter}`, { // and here I put value from state in param q
   ...args,
    headers: {/.....},
  });
 return response.json();      
}
```

### Search.js:

```
export default ({ value, userEnteredValue }) => {
  return (
    <div className="search">
        <input type="text" className="searchInput" onChange={userEnteredValue} value={value}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you make a codesandbox.io demo?
It's a bit difficult to debug without seeing all the moving parts.

Comment: Looking at it right now, might take some time.

Comment: I misread your question and it seems like you're asking about your server side.
It all depends on your servers implementation, however you put on the client code.
Please provide your servers code or a clarification for this.